# How to set spinner window position on below of a spinner

Tags: android, position, android-spinner

Is there any method to set default spinner position , I just want to show my spinner window below the spinner title but normally when we click on spinner ,the window popup on above the title ,so is there any way to show the popup below the title.

Comment: you can open listview as popup instead spinner

Comment: yes ajay I can but I am asking is there any way?

Comment: not in my view when popwindow is show your whole item in the window you can manage it with textview just above the spinner so when window is open you can set current sleeted value in textview and set appropriate visibility to textview with window state of spinner make sure your spinner mode is android:spinnerMode="dropdown"

Comment: just add this to your spinner in xml:  android:spinnerMode="dropdown"

Comment: Ok thank you guys for your answer let me try and let you know

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For this spinner, you may use like this

**android:dropDownVerticalOffset="40dp"**

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
      android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
      android:dropDownVerticalOffset="40dp"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Now Drop down will show as per your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

I preferable use this approach and not dealing with ViewTreeObserver

```
mSortingSpinner.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mSortingSpinner.setDropDownVerticalOffset(mSortingSpinner.getDropDownVerticalOffset() + mSortingSpinner.getHeight());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

For **dropdown** Spinner mode you can use this:

```
mSortingSpinner.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        mSortingSpinner.setDropDownVerticalOffset(
                mSortingSpinner.getDropDownVerticalOffset() + mSortingSpinner.getHeight());
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            mSortingSpinner.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        } else {
            mSortingSpinner.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
    }
});
```

This set vertical offset of dropdown by spinner height.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [Rami El-bouhi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8532826/rami-el-bouhi)'s code to the **Kotlin** way:

```
spinner.post {
  dropDownVerticalOffset += height
}
```